# Refinery CMS undefined method `validators_on'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I get a undefined method `validators_on' for NilClass:Class error when i try to use Refinery CMS.

the block of code is :

```
  class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  alias :orig_label :label

  # add a '*' after the field label if the field is required - Added in the password field label
  def label(method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options && content_or_options.class == Hash
      options = content_or_options
    else
      content = content_or_options
    end

    required_mark = ''
    required_mark = ' *'.html_safe if object.class.validators_on(method).map(&:class).include? ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator

    content ||= method.to_s.humanize
    content = content + required_mark

    self.orig_label(method, content, options || {}, &block)
  end
end
```

I believe it's not getting the " *" when i add it in my view. See view code:

```
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="registration">
        <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
            <li><%= error %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <form action="/sign-up" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

          <label for="user[email]">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="user[email]" value="<%= @user.email %>" id="user[email]">

          <label for="user[password]">Password *</label>
          <input type="password" name="user[password]" value="" id="user[password]">

          <label for="user[password_confirmation]">Password Confirmation</label>
          <input type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" value="" id="user[password_confirmation]">

          <p><input type="submit" class='btn' value="Sign Up"></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

From what i can tell it appears that when this page is rendered the "*" isn't being read by the method. What would cause this?

Another weird thing is that when i run this code on heroku i have no problems. But when I try to run on my local machine or ninefold it breaks. Was there a depreciation of "validations_on" between ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.3? I can't find any evidence of this.

Answer (score 0):

For this version of the app I had to populate the database in order to get anything to work.